# R: How to change color of warning from black to red?

Tags: r, logging, colors, warnings

I use `futile.logger` package. 
I want to change the color of warnings from black to red for `flog.warn` function. 
Is it possible?
Or, maybe, can I just change the color of the message using `flog.info` function?
What other functions (except the basic `warning()`) can be used for these purposes?